# Is the change ΔG for an ideal gas unknown?

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy, ideal-gas

When one is introduced to the first law of thermodynamics, one learns that enthalpy is only a function of temperature, and calculating its changes is straightforward
\begin{equation}
   \Delta H^\pu{ig} = H^\pu{ig}(T_2) - H^\pu{ig}(T_1) =
   \int_{T_1}^{T_2} C_\mathrm{p}^\pu{ig}(T) \; dT \tag{1}
\end{equation}
When the second law is introduced, one also learns that the entropy is a function of pressure and temperature, and calculating its changes is also straightforward
\begin{equation}
   \Delta S^\pu{ig} = S^\pu{ig}(p_2,T_2) - S^\pu{ig}(p_1,T_1) =
   \int_{T_1}^{T_2} \frac{C_\mathrm{p}^\pu{ig}(T)}{T} \; dT -R \ln\left(\frac{p_2}{p_1}\right) \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Finally, when the Gibbs energy is introduced, one is presented with the fundamental equation for constant composition systems
$$ \mathrm{d}G = V\mathrm{d}p - S\mathrm{d}T \tag{3} $$
And Eq. (3) for an ideal gas, at constant temperature $T$, gives also a famous relationship to calculate the changes in pressure. We replace $V^\pu{ig} = RT/p$, integrate, and get
\begin{equation}
  \Delta G^\pu{ig} = G^\pu{ig}(p_2,T) - G^\pu{ig}(p_1,T) = RT \ln\left(\frac{p_2}{p_1}\right) 
  \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Now, I am interested in calculating the changes in Gibbs energy when the **temperature** changes and the pressure is constant. However, one faces the funny situation of being unable to obtain an expression in this case. For a constant pressure process, integrating Eq. (3) is not particularly attractive since one gets the entropy in the right-hand side
\begin{equation}
  \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_p = -S \tag{5}
\end{equation}
It is possible to manipulate Eq. (5) and obtain the Gibbs-Helmholtz equation to eliminate $S$ for $H$
\begin{equation}
  \left[\frac{\partial (G^\pu{ig}/T)}{\partial T}\right]_p = -\frac{H^\pu{ig}}{T^2} \tag{6}
\end{equation}
and, for example, try to establish a relationship in a simpler case, of a constant heat capacity gas. Eq. (1) integrated for a reference temperature $T_0$ automatically leads to
\begin{equation}
  \left[\frac{\partial (G^\pu{ig}/T)}{\partial T}\right]_p = -\frac{H^\pu{ig}(T_0) +
   C_\mathrm{p}^\pu{ig}(T - T_0)}{T^2} \tag{7}
\end{equation}
And no matter what the effort, I can never obtain a simple expression that *only* depends on the fundamental variables $p$ and $T$
$$ \Delta G^\pu{ig} = G^\pu{ig}(p,T_2) - G^\pu{ig}(p,T_2) = f(p,T_2) - f(p,T_1) $$
And thus, the changes of $\Delta G^\pu{ig}$ for a non-isothermal process in an ideal gas are impossible to calculate. A similar argument can be raised for calculating the changes in the Helmholtz energy $\Delta A^\pu{ig}$ when the temperature changes, and again, one cannot find an equation.

Is this correct? And if it is, why is so?

**Edit** Doing by definition of $\Delta G$ won't work because one faces an issue in the entropy term, impossible to resolve
\begin{align}
  \Delta G^\pu{ig} &=
  [H^\pu{ig}(T_2) - T_2S^\pu{ig}(p_2,T_2)] -
  [H^\pu{ig}(T_1) - T_1S^\pu{ig}(p_1,T_1)] \\ &=
  [H^\pu{ig}(T_2) - H^\pu{ig}(T_1)] - \color{red}{[T_2S^\pu{ig}(p_2,T_2) -
  T_1S^\pu{ig}(p_1,T_1)]}
\end{align}

Comment: It seems $\int_{T_1=0}^{T_2} {\frac{C_p \mathrm{d}T}{T}}$ is easier for real matter, as $\lim_{T_1 \to 0} {(\frac{C_p}{T})} = 0$ for it,  but $\lim_{T_1 \to 0} {(\frac{C_p}{T})} = \infty$ for ideal gas.

Comment: @Poutnik Hello Poutnik. In the first case you speak about solids, this is, the Debye model of solids that states $C_V \propto T^3$ and continuous at $T\rightarrow 0^+$? Is this right? And for the second case, how do you see that $T=0$ is making a problem in trying to find $\Delta G$?

Comment: YEst, I do mean the Debye model. Integral dT/T from T=0 K is infinite, in attempts to get S as integration for T=0 K for ideal gas, as C_p,ig, does not go to zero.

Comment: @Poutnik So, if we don't include vibrational modes of motion, then $C_\mathrm{p}^\pu{ig} \neq f(T)$ and thus $\nexists \lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} \int_a^{T_2} \frac{C_\mathrm{p}^\pu{ig}}{T} \; \mathrm{d}T$. You smell that this is the source of the problem?

Comment: Imagine helium is an ideal gas, then it will still have Cp=3/2.R + R J/K/mol. / $\lim_{T \to 0+}{(\frac {dS}{dT})}=+\infty$ // I do not say it is the problem source, but rather additional problem. My TD is after leaving  university 34 years ago quite dusty.

Comment: Bad luck is it is infinity if integrated too.

Comment: Could you not use the Sakur-Tetrode eqn. to calculate S in eqn 5? The entropy of the ideal gas is just due to translational motion and this can be found via the partition function and so to the ST eqn.

Comment: @porphyrin Sorry for this late reply. I wouldn't like to mix statistical thermodynamics here, my idea is to do it classically. However, still the unknown value $S(T_1,V_1)$ for the Sackur-Tetrode value will appear, if you integrate. Do you coincide?

Comment: The (classical) entropy for the ideal gas is $S=C_p\ln(T)-nR\ln(p)+S_0$ at constant $C_p$ and $S_0$ is a constant, can you use this in eqn 5 ?

Comment: @porphyrin Although I don't like that indefinite integration we try. At constant pressure $p$ we would get $S(p,T) = C_\mathrm{p}\ln(T) + S_0$. Integrated that would lead to $G(p,T_2) - G(p,T_1) = C_\mathrm{p} [(T_2\ln(T_2) - T_2) - (T_1 \ln(T_1) - T_1)] + S_0 (T_2 - T_1)$. This again leads to an undefined $\Delta G$, because in its form of a *change* depends on the arbitrarily number you give to $S_0$.

Comment: Yes, there will always be some constant, but this is calculable from the ST eqn which is effectively the same as $S=\cdots$ I quoted earlier.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  The value of $\Delta G$ you get is always going to depend on the value of S in the initial state or in a reference state.  But that does not limit the utility of the G function in establishing phase- and chemical equilibrium..